How to add variable autocompletion in codeMirror using brackets in React typescript?
I'm trying to use this to trigger the autocomplete: {{ but not showing the opinions. I see the variables perfectly in the console; it triggers without a problem but does not open the opinion list.
import ReactCodeMirror from "@uiw/react-codemirror";
import { markdown } from "@codemirror/lang-markdown";
import { python } from "@codemirror/lang-python";
import { json } from "@codemirror/lang-json";
import { VariableType } from "@/models/WorkflowDesignerModelConfig";
import { autocompletion } from "@codemirror/autocomplete";
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

function myCompletions(context: any, listOfPromptVariables: string[]) {
  let word = context.matchBefore(/\{\{\w*/);
  if (!word || (word.from === word.to && !context.explicit)) return null;

  const options = listOfPromptVariables.map((variable) => ({
    label: variable,
    type: "variable",
    apply: `{{${variable}}}`,
  }));

  return {
    from: word.from,
    options: options,
    validFor: /^\{\{\w*$/,
  };
}

function CodeEditor({
  variableType,
  listOfPromptVariables,
  editorContent,
  onEditorChange,
}: any) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(editorContent);
  const handleEditorChange = useCallback((content: any) => {
    onEditorChange(content);
    setValue(content);
    console.log(content)
  }, [value]);

  const codeOptions = {
    lineNumbers: true,
    tabSize: 2,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    foldGutter: true,
    autocompletion: true,
    drawSelection: true,
    closeBrackets: false,
  };

  return (
    <div className="px-5 h-[74%]">
      <h1 className="my-5 text-base font-medium pb-5 border-b-2 border-dashed">
        {variableType == VariableType.SwaggerDoc
          ? "SwaggerDoc"
          : variableType == VariableType.PromptTemplate
          ? "PromptTemplate"
          : variableType == VariableType.JsonSchema
          ? "JsonSchema"
          : ""}
      </h1>
      <div className="pt-3 h-full">
        <ReactCodeMirror
          value={value}
          theme={"light"}
          extensions={[
            markdown(),
            python(),
            json(),
            autocompletion({
              override: [
                (context) => myCompletions(context, listOfPromptVariables),
              ],
            }),
          ]}
          height={"77vh"}
          onChange={handleEditorChange}
          basicSetup={codeOptions}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CodeEditor;

I tried to trigger with these characters, the brackets, but it's not opening the list of options, so I cannot add any variable. The trigger works, and it fills the options variable.
